# Why PyCharm highlights same inspection violation (Type Checker) by two different methods?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have some code like this, there are 2 type violations. Why first is marked as Warning, but the second one is only as Typo? When suppress inspection for statement, the noinspections are the same - PyTypeChecker.

[image]